# UNUserNotificationCenter Trigger not firing

Tags: ios10, unusernotificationcenter

I am attempting to use the UserNotifications Frameworks for iOS 10.

Notifications seem to work great if I do not pass in a trigger. They get presented right away in app. But I need to pass in a delay for the trigger. Can anyone see the flaw in my code? It should make it a 15 second delay but it never goes off.

```
UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello!" arguments:nil];
content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Hello_message_body"
                                                     arguments:nil];
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
content.categoryIdentifier = @"WhatUpsw";


NSString *imageName = @"hug2";

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:imageName withExtension:@"jpg"];


UNNotificationAttachment *attachment = [UNNotificationAttachment attachmentWithIdentifier:imageName URL:url options:nil error:nil];
content.attachments = @[attachment];                          

// Deliver the notification in five seconds.
UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger* trigger = [     UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger
                                              triggerWithTimeInterval:15 repeats:NO];

UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"FiveSecondsw"
                                                                      content:content trigger:trigger];
// Schedule the notification.
[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"All good!: %@", request);
    }
}];
```

also checking pending requests i see:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x17024d170>(
<UNNotificationRequest: 0x1702235c0; identifier: FiveSecond, content:   <UNNotificationContent: 0x17010bd00; title: Hello!, subtitle: (null), body: Hello_message_body, categoryIdentifier: , launchImageName: , peopleIdentifiers: (
), threadIdentifier: , attachments: (
), badge: (null), sound: <UNNotificationSound: 0x1700b4580>, hasDefaultAction: YES, defaultActionTitle: (null), shouldAddToNotificationsList: YES, shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground: NO, shouldLockDevice: NO, shouldPauseMedia: NO, isSnoozeable: NO, fromSnooze: NO, darwinNotificationName: (null), darwinSnoozedNotificationName: (null), trigger: <UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger: 0x170223780; repeats: NO, timeInterval: 10.000000>>
)
```

Comment: Try this again with a different identifier value

Comment: @bhakti123 Ive tried. If I start a new project, boom works as expected. In this project it just doesn't, and I don't understand why. Very strange.

Comment: This is because every notification that you schedule has the same identifier. UNUserNotificationCenter needs different identifiers for different notifications. Because there already exists a notification with this identifier, you never get the second one that you schedule.

Comment: @bhakti123 I understand that, but none fire. The above code never fires. It should fire after 15 seconds and just doesnt. If I take the trigger away it fires everytime. I should be able to press a button and fire a notification off anytime

Comment: are you scheduling this on a button click?

Comment: @bhakti123 No view did load in View controller

Comment: Can you show the whole code?

Comment: @bhakti123 Thank you for your attempts to help!

Comment: Did it work ? Were you able to solve the problem ?

Comment: @bhakti123 The answer below is what helped, Im still not exactly sure what happened. Im going to chalk it up to xcode and iOS beta's.

Answer (score 7):

Does the problem occur only if your app is running in the foreground? If you close the app or switch to another one before the trigger time is reached, does the notification work properly?

In order to have notifications appear while the app is running, you need to set a `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in your `appController(_:didFinishLaunching:)`:

```
func appController(_ appController: TVApplicationController, didFinishLaunching options: [String : Any]?) {
  // ...

  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

  // ...
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
  completionHandler(.alert)
}
```

The delegate needs to be set before launching is complete.

Comment: Thank you, coming from an android background this was very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent the last 2 days fighting with this problem on iOS 13.  It turns out that my notification identifier was either too long, or because I was using the same string for a localized string for the title/message it wasn't working.

Changing the ID of the notification so that it was 1. short, and 2. not the same as anything else solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am running iOS 10.3 Beta and Xcode 8.3 beta 2 so it may just be a bug. To fix this issue I deleted the content extension, restarted Xcode and added the extension once again. After that every message came through.